# Why is the ground state energy of particle in a box not zero?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue, ground-state

I understand that we want to solve for non-zero values of wave function. I always thought that is to avoid the obvious answer to Schrodinger equation. But from physical standpoint, if we have a particle of mass $m$, is it really impossible for it to have energy of zero? From mathematical point of view shouldn't the ground state energy of every system be zero? If yes, what does that mean? Nothingness. Void as ground state?

Comment: But isn't there a zero-energy ground state for the particle-in-the-box, by taking $n=0$ in $E_n=\frac{n^2\hbar^2\pi^2}{2ma^2}$?

Comment: Did you mean the quantum harmonic oscillator?

Comment: @probably_someone exactly that was my question. A textbook I read says that the ground state is at n=1. I do not understand whether avoiding zero is arbitrary or theoretically/physically meaningful.

Comment: @probably_someone  n=0 is not a legitimate choice for the quantum number in this case, for example if you put that into your wavefunction for the particle in a box you obtain nonsense

Comment: @R.Rankin Depends on what you mean by "nonsense." You get a wavefunction that is identically zero everywhere, which means that there is nothing in the box.

Comment: @probably_someone  fair enough, yet that is hardly an energy level for the particle. I think the OP's question is better understood in the context of  QFT, second quantization and considering all particles as operators on the vacuum state (which itself has a 0 expectation value for energy) not the nonrelativistic jargon.

Comment: Another way to formulate the issue is that if we allowed a ground state with $n=0$, it wouldn't be normalizable, as the wave function is identically zero. If we would've allowed $n=0$, and supposedly prepare a system in this ground (stationary) state we would have $\int \psi \psi^*=0$, instead of $\int \psi \psi^*=1$ as required from a quantum state.

Comment: Related: [Why is the ground state important in condensed matter physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591584/247642)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As far as most textbooks on (non-relativistic) quantum mechanics go, we do not consider the solution for $n=0$ because it gives us a trivial solution (and we interpret it to mean that there is no particle inside the box/well).

However, if there were a ground state with zero energy for a square well potential, it would imply that (since the particle has zero energy), it will be at rest inside the square well, and this will clearly violate Heisenberg's uncertainty principle!

By confining a particle to a very small region in space, it acquires a small but finite momentum. So, if the particle is restricted to move in a region of width $\Delta x \sim a$ (i.e., the entire length of the well), we can calculate the **minimum uncertainty** in momentum (using the uncertainty principle) and it comes out to be $\Delta p \sim \hbar/a$. And, this in turn gives us the minimum kinetic energy of the order $\hbar^2/(2ma^2)$. This (qualitatively) agrees with the exact value of the ground state energy.

So physically, the existence of a zero-point energy is a necessary feature of a quantum mechanical system. It indicates that the particle should exhibit 'a minimum motion' due to localization. Classically, the lowest possible energy of system corresponds to the minimum value of the potential energy (with kinetic energy being zero). But in quantum mechanics,the lowest energy state corresponds to the minimum value of the sum of both potential and kinetic energy, and this leads to a finite ground state or zero point energy.

Comment: I understand your line of reasoning. Shouldn't this be mathematically addressed in the very formulation of Schrodinger equation? Is it fine to put an extra statement saying let's avoid some mathematical solution to keep it consistent with uncertainty principle?

Comment: Well, Heisenberg's uncertainty principle follows from the postulates of quantum mechanics and the Schrödinger equation or the time evolution of the system is itself another postulate. So, as far as I understand it, everything is consistent with the postulates of quantum mechanics here, as it should be. We are not adding "extra statements" arbitrarily, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

The zero of the energy is completely arbitrary, as the zero of time or space.

In fact, suppose that the ground state energy of $H $ is $a $, then $H-a I$, where $I $ is the identity operator, has ground state energy zero and the same eigenvectors of $H $. In addition, it generates the same time evolution (apart from a non-physical phase factor). Therefore it is, from the physical standpoint, indistinguishable from the original one.

Comment: What you are suggesting essentially amounts to perturbing the Hamiltonian, right? Basically, perturbations of order greater than one will vanish for a constant perturbation in general. We can calculate the wave function as well. But is this true always? We will run into trouble if the (unperturbed) energy spectrum is degenerate (e.g., while solving for a 3D box).

Comment: Adding a constant is a very trivial perturbation. And it does not do anything apart from shifting the spectrum by a fixed numerical amount.

Comment: We can shift a Hamiltonian by any constant, but the problem here is that, because you'd choose an $\hbar$-dependent constant, you wouldn't be quantising the classical Hamiltonian, which is written on the assumption $\hbar=0$. So there actually is a physical interpretation to be made of the zero-point energy that this just-shift-the-potential argument overlooks. noir1993 has provided the box's interpretation; for the harmonic oscillator it's that $\left[ a,\,a^\dagger\right]\propto\hbar$ because $\left[ x,\,p\right]\propto\hbar$.

Comment: But whenever we are dealing with perturbations, the coupling constant (here, $a$) should be small (otherwise we can not expand it in a power series). For an electron, the ground state is roughly $30 eV$ which is not negligible and I doubt if non-degenerate perturbation theory would apply for such a (quantum mechanically) huge perturbation.

Comment: @noir1993 If we can't analytically deduce the new Hamiltonian's spectrum we need small perturbations to use Taylor series, but in this case the spectrum is trivial to obtain.

Comment: @J.G. That an Hamiltonian is the quantization of a classical symbol is a matter of convenience, not a physical requirement. The physical requirement is that in the limit you will obtain the correct classical behavior. And that is still true if the Hamiltonian is shifted by the $\hslash$-dependent zero point energy. In addition, as far as I know, only energy differences are observable experimentally (e.g. measuring the frequency of the emitted or absorbed radiation); therefore the ground state energy is not measurable.

Comment: Finally, also mathematically it is easy to see that shifting it to any desired (finite) value does not change anything relevant. In this context, what really matters physically is that the Hamiltonian is bounded from below (i.e. the system cannot emit energy indefinitely).

Comment: This answer is somewhat off the track: while you can shift total energy by an arbitrary amount, you can't avoid the nonzero mean kinetic energy in the ground state.

Answer (score 0):

***I am sharing my opinion$ \ :\ \ \ $***
As we know that quantum mechanical discrete energy states appears only when we consider a bound state problem . Generally it's told that ground state energy can never be zero quantum mechanically .Now think that you have a bound state problem . That means the particle is bounded in some region . Then if we get a zero energy state (means energy is zero : as $n=0  \ in \  E_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2\hslash^2}{2ma^2} \ $ particle in the box ) then the particle will have no energy in that state . Means it  will be resting at some definite position . Then you can predict it's position perfectly by measuring as it is resting and you can also tell the momentum = $0$ as it's in rest . But Heisenberg uncertainty Principle clearly tells us that $ \ \Delta x.\Delta p \geq \frac{\hslash}{2} \ $  . But then this product will be zero . In this way zero energy violates the H.U.P . And so it is eliminated .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The $n=0$ case leads to a wavefunction that is zero everywhere, so it can't define a normalized probability law. Therefore it isn't a physically possible state for the particle anyway. Also, when something is the result of a logic-based reasoning, it isn't an opinion. ;)