# How should I interpret eigenvectors in second quantization?

Tags: linear-algebra, second-quantization, phase-diagram

a) I would like to ask, if knowledge about eigenvectors in second quantization is important and what do they mean? Let's just say, I create Fock space [(NumberOfSites)x(Permutations) matrix], then I solve Hubbard Hamiltonian [(NumberOfSites)x(NumberOfSites) matrix]. After diagonalisation of this Hamiltonian I get eigenvalues [Energies] and eigenvectors.How should I interpret these eigenvectors?

b) How can I know/calculate what phase does system has? Basically, how is someone able to tell which phase does system has just from Hamiltonian?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvectors in second quantization play the same role as in the first quantization - mainly determining the physical properties of the system. In particular, the ground state (i.e., the lowest energy eigenvectors) is the subject of many studies, books, articles, etc.:[Why is the ground state important in condensed matter physics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/591584/247642)

If by saying *"phase"* you refer to phase transitions, then Hamiltonian itself does not determine a phase - it is determined by the (thermodynamics) state of the system. E.g., the system may go from one phase to another when temperature changes, while the Hamiltonian remains the same.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really helped me.